# Ubuntu execute .jar as non-admin user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a .jar file that needs to be run as an admin user but I want to execute it from a standard desktop users account (eg. they are not admin and do not have sudo priviledges)

I have tried using the visudo file with nopasswd but from what I can see this only applies to admin users

I dont want to have to enter an admin password

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is - its not possible.

Your "standard" users just don't have *execute* permission for that file.
This is one of the basic security principles of operating systems in general.

You can check the permissions of your file with `ls -l /path/to/your/file`.

And the only legal solution is to set the executing permission for your "standard" users.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be an admin but are no admin, then I guess you just can't.

If you don't actually need to be an admin, then `java -jar $jarfile` should do the trick.

If you need to be an admin but don't care about running on the actual desktop OS, then you might use a container (Ubuntu ships LXC, for example) or a virtual machine (look at Virtualbox), where the user can be an admin without actually being an admin on the underlying OS.